# How to read a widget's stylesheet?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I know how to ***set*** a style sheet for a widget (using `setStyleSheet`), but is there some way I can ***read*** a widget's stylesheet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just call the `styleSheet()` method. [PyQt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#styleSheet) - not that expressive :). [Qt Docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Qt Docs link doesn't work anymore and first one doesn't seems to provide a useful answer.